# 'flutter' in git bash returns 'Where is not recognized as in internal...' and 'Error: unable to find git in your path'

Tags: flutter, powershell, git-bash, npx

So I recently downloaded flutter on my windows 11 via flutter's website, and added the flutter/bin directory to my path user variable. I then confirmed it when I typed 'where flutter' in my git bash terminal to which it returned its location. However, when I go to type 'flutter' I am returned with:

```
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

What's weird is that the error doesn't even refer to flutter and instead refers to 'where' and git --both of which work fine on git bash. Fortunately, flutter works fine on Windows PowerShell. I noticed this problem too when using npx commands on git bash. It wouldn't work on git bash but would work on Windows Powershell. I would highly appreciate it if anyone can help.

[flutter doctor typed in powershell and gitbash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrqEj.png)

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of what your are writing in the git bash command line?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: OK, that's a bit weird: your mingw64 shell (presumably a bash variant) ran `flutter` using CMD.EXE instead of using a shell. Why it did that, I don't know, but that's the problem. Feeding [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=when+does+mingw64+bash+use+cmd.exe+to+run+a+program) to google comes up with some StackOverflow Q&A that doesn't seem applicable. That's as far as I have gotten; you need a Windows user here.

Comment: (I adjusted your tags as this seems to have nothing to do with Git, but may have something to do with bash-ports-to-Windows such as git-bash.)

Comment: If it helps, I placed the flutter/bin directory on my desktop as opposed to putting it in my Program Files dir.  I did it as per the flutter installation instructions (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows). Do you think git bash maybe has trouble accessing executables outside the Program Files directory?